# How to work with excel in python in a better way?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I am currently using xlwt to generate a report in excel based on the data I have but the problem there is I have to hardcore the formulas and if I need to add a row in the middle of the sheet all the entries below that row needs to be arranged properly and need to recheck all the formulas.

currently my meta file for sheet data is like following:

```
STUDENTS_ROW_IDX = 5 MARKS_ROW = 10

SHEET_META = { 
const.STUDENT:{ 
const.NUM_OF_STUDENTS:{
 "idx": STUDENT_ROW_IDX },
 const.NUM_OF_PASSED_STUDENTS:{ 
"idx":STUDENT_ROW_IDX + 2 
} 
}, 
const.MARKS:{ 
const.TOTAL_MARKS:{
 "idx":MARKS_ROW 
}, 
"formula": {
 const.AVG_MARKS:{
 "idx":MARKS_ROW + 3, 
 "value":"IF(X5 = 0, 0, X10/X5)" 
}
 } 
}
```

The problem here is for avg marks I need to change the value from X10 to the new value if the row for total students changes. Is there a better way to handle excel with python.

Comment: Why do the calculations in excel? You could do them in python (using numpy or pandas) and then write the results to excel if you need to.

Comment: Because you may want to distribute to someone not savy in Python and allow them to modify the values on the fly. Basically the reason people use Excel in the first place.

Comment: If that's the case then fine, just didn't want him to be making things more difficult for himself unnecessarily.